# Where and how to enable '--shell-escape' or '--enable-write18' of pdflatex.exe in LaTeXTools of Sublime Text?

Tags: miktex, shell-escape, sublime-text

I know how to deal with the problem with the older version of LaTeXTools. But recently LaTeXTools has been updated, which turn out to deprive me of knowing what to do.

I use Windows+MikTex, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the more recent versions of LaTeXTools, enabling this has become less hackish. There are two methods that can be used to set flags for `pdflatex`. Either:

1. At the start of your text file include a "magic" comment like this: `%!TEX option = --shell-escape`

Or

2. In the `builder_settings` section of LaTeXTools setting file, add a key "options" like this:

   `"options": [ "--shell-escape" ],`

Comment: Does anybody now if it is th same using LuaLaTeX and Sublime Text?

Comment: @israel: should be

Answer (score 1):

See answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176286/how-to-modify-the-latextools-sublime-settings-to-make-it-work-in-windows-miktex).

```
"tap Preferences->package settings->LaTeXTools->Reconfigure LaTeXTools 
and migrate settings in order to create the LaTeXTools.sublime-settings file."
```